# Smartphone recording distortion

Tags: mobile

I have a Lumia 950 XL that can record 4k at 30 FPS and 1080p at 60 FPS. Everythings working great, but I'm having the same issues that I've had with my old Samsung smartphone when recording video: when moving, the recording seems to pop in and out. Not sure how to describe it, but it what it seems like is that it's as if my lens were submerged in water and the water is moving in and out of perspective. What is the explanation for this? How do we prevent this from happening?

This seems to happen for quick or jerky movements but not steady ones though.

EDIT: Here's a sample video:

Comment: Can you post screenshots? Offhand, it looks like an autofocus issue.

Comment: Will do @Mulvya , but in a few hours, but I will also try the autofocus lead and let you know!

Comment: @Mulvya added a sample video...I also tried manually setting the focus but it is still the same

Comment: Ah, rolling shutter. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DG4OjpD3Zow and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mQ0hS7l9ckY

Comment: Thanks for the informative and entertaining vids @Mulvya .